# Proving one function is greater than another in a certain interval

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality, proof-verification

Given $f(x,y)=y~(1-x)$ and $g(x,y)=(1 - x^y)$, how can I prove that $f(x,y) \geq g(x,y)$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and for all $y \geq 1$?

From my tries, it seems that there are two possibilities:

1. If $xy \leq x-1$, then in the inequation $y - 1 - xy \geq -x^y$ the left-hand side will be always positive and the right hand side will be always negative. So, it is ok.
2. Otherwise, if $xy > x-1$, then I could not find a way to prove it.

   Any suggestions?

Comment: Did it! Thanks to @wythagoras.

Assuming $x$ and $y$ such that $x \in [0, 1]$ and $x \geq 1$. I want to show that $y(1 - x) \geq 1 - x^y$. Rewriting it as $x^y \geq 1 + y(x - 1)$ (Equation A.1):
When $x = 0$ or $x = 1$, we can easily observe that the affirmation is true, because $y \geq 1$ by definition.
For the other values of $x$, we can use the Bernoulli’s inequality: $(1 + i) j \geq 1 + ij$, where $i \geq -1$, $i=0$ is a real number and $y \geq 2$ an integer value. Substituting the values of $x$ and $y$ in Equation A.1 respectively by $i + 1$ and $j$, the claim is proved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use Bernoulli's inequality to prove $x^y \geq y(x-1)+1$.

Comment: Did it! Thanks!

Assuming $x$ and $y$ such that $x \in [0, 1]$ and $x \geq 1$. I want to show that $y(1 - x) \geq 1 - x^y$. Rewriting it as $x^y \geq 1 + y(x - 1)$ (Equation A.1):
When $x = 0$ or $x = 1$, we can easily observe that the affirmation is true, because $y \geq 1$ by definition.
For the other values of $x$, we can use the Bernoulli’s inequality: $(1 + i) j \geq 1 + ij$, where $i \geq -1$, $i=0$ is a real number and $y \geq 2$ an integer value. Substituting the values of $x$ and $y$ in Equation A.1 respectively by $i + 1$ and $j$, the claim is proved.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that the inequality is true for $x = 0, 1$. So assume $0 < x < 1$ . Consider $f(x) = x^y$ for a fixed $y \geq 1$. We have: $f(x,y) \geq g(x,y) \iff y \geq \dfrac{1-x^y}{1-x}= yc^{y-1}, x < c < 1$ by MVT. But $y \geq yc^{y-1}$ is true since $1 \geq c^{y-1} \iff 0 \geq (y-1)\ln c$ which is true since $\ln c \leq 0$. Thus the claim is established.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $y\ge 1$ and minimize $h(x)=f(x,y)-g(x,y)$. You get $h'(x)=y(x^{y-1}-1)\le 0$ for $x\in[0,1]$, hence, $h$ is decreasing and the minimum is $\min h(x)=h(1)=0$. It means that $h(x)\ge 0$ in $[0,1]$.